# Hive - Count the number of records for each day in a DB

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table that has millions of records and each row is a unique record that has a date - example below:

```
name, date, item
bob, jan 1, brush
jim, jan 1, computer
mary, jan 1, mouse
bill, jan 2, mop
james, jan 3, desk
```

I want the output to just show me how many records there are per day. I tried:

```
select distinct(date), count(distinct(date)) distinct for date
from DB
```

and

```
select distinct(date) from DB group by count(distinct(date))
```

I realize I can't just do count(distinct(date)) because that just gives me the number of total distinct dates. I want the output to be:

```
date, count
jan 1, 3
jan 2, 1
jan 3, 1
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should study Group by https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and aggregate functions such as count, avg, sum, min, max ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic `group by` query:

```
select date, count(*)
from DB
group by date;
```

I would suggest that you spend a bit of time studying the basics of SQL queries.  There are many online resources.